# Jquery Select closest Form element and remove Class

Tags: jquery

```
   <p class="align-with-aes">
               <a class="with-icon manage-link active" href="#">
                   Manage Reference
               </a>
           </p>

    <form method="post" class="updateForm hide" novalidate="novalidate">                                                                                                           
       <p class="align-with-aes">
         <a class="with-icon add-new-line" id="add-line" href="#add-new-line">
            <i class="icon-add-inv"></i>Add new Reference
         </a>
       </p>
       <div class="row ref-update-button">
         <div class="span6">
            <button class="submitReference loadRef btn" id="submitReference"><i class="icon-submit"></i>Submit Reference</button>
         </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**jquery**

```
    $( ".manage-link" ).click(function() {
        $(this).parent().closest('form').removeClass('hide');
    });
```

here I am tring to get the closest form when I click on a link having class name **"manage-link"**
this is not working. am I doing anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your link and form are not in the same part of the DOM tree, you might as well do a global `$('form')` search. Most other solution will not tolerate future changes to the DOM structure.

e.g.

```
$('form').removeClass('hide')
```

**Better options are:**

**1)** If you want multiple forms on a page, add a parent div that surrounds both branches and use `closest()` to get to that element, then `find()` the form within it.

```
<div class="formwrapper">
    <p class="align-with-aes"> <a class="with-icon manage-link active" href="#">
        Manage Reference
        </a>
    </p>
    <form method="post" class="updateForm hide" novalidate="novalidate">
       ...
    </form>
<div>
```

and use

```
$(this).closest('.formwrapper').find('form').removeClass('hide');
```

or **2)** add identifying information to the link, so it knows what the related form is. In this example I add a `data-form=".updateForm"` attribute containing a selector:

```
<div class="formwrapper">
    <p class="align-with-aes"> <a class="with-icon manage-link active" href="#" data-form=".updateForm">
        Manage Reference
        </a>
    </p>
    <form method="post" class="updateForm hide" novalidate="novalidate">
       ...
    </form>
<div>
```

and use with:

```
$($(this).data('form')).removeClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 3):

That form is not the parent of clicked element:

```
$(this).closest('p').siblings('form').removeClass('hide');
```

use `.closest()` instead of `.parent()` because if in any case your markup gets changed *(if existing elems get wrapped in other elems like span/strong)* you don't have to worry about that.

use `.siblings()` because parent of the clicked element is the sibling.

Answer (score 1):

Try ths:

```
  $( ".manage-link" ).click(function() {
        $(this).closest('p').siblings('form').removeClass('hide');
    });
```

This might work!

Comment: Why would anyone do closest on `body` (e.g. `closest('body').find(`) when `$('form')` effectively does the same thing?